# How to retrive value of xforms:select in orbeon forms on client side (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, orbeon, xforms

I have next problem, when I'm trying to retrieve value from xforms:select elements I retrieve some encrypted value like **"eKdObOh+XakQQkcJayfQArlH+Y5M4huLkvqoSAsN7P8="** while I know the real value, which I'm set in the form constructor is **"ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS"**.

I found this function `ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(controlIdOrElement)` but it returns the same encrypted value.

Is there any way to retrieve real value from xforms:select elements, or may be some configs which I have to enable/disable, or may be there some common algorithm which transforms real value to encrypted one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value is not private, you can put the following attribute on the `xforms:select` control:

```
xxforms:encrypt-item-values="false"
```

This will leave the value returned by `getValue()` unencrypted.

You can also set this attribute per page, on the first `xforms:model` of your form, or even globally in properties. In general it is recommended to leave the values encrypted unless you are sure that they are confidential.

Comment: @ebruchez: Hi, can we put this property at each control level. I thought we have to set in properties-local.xml if we dont want the encrypted options.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma Yes, this can be put on individual controls.